# Deduplicate/combine objects based on an attribute

Tags: python-3.x

I have multiple objects in a list, each objects having multiple attributes:
The attributes can have a string value or None. Example:

Ex1:

```
name = 'apolodor'
descr = 'apolodor intunates'
ext = '123456'
int  = ' None'
```

Ex2:

```
 name = 'apolodor'
 descr = 'apolodor ascuria'
 ext = 'None'
 int  = ' 593'
```

Ex3:

```
 name = 'apolodor'
 descr = 'apolodor antohia'
 ext = 'None'
 int  = ' 593'
```

If the objects have the same `name`(lowercase), I have some rules:

For ext, int: get a values if is None
For descr: add all values, with a separator.

Result for the 3 examples above:

Result:

```
 name = 'apolodor'
 descr = 'apolodor intunates || apolodor ascuria || apolodor antohia'
 ext = 123456'
 int  = ' 593'
```

I'm thinking to use loop thru the list of objects, and create a new list for each object.

```
count = []

for l in objects_list:
  count_in = []
  count.append(l)
```

But I need somehow to know if I already have the name, and searching every time thru all the list that I created doesn't look efficient.

Comment: Use a `set`....

Comment: or a `dict` with the names as keys